# MYSQL can't start service on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7

EDIT: This happened most of the times, due to power failure.

Two things which worked for me.
1. Knowing how to change root password in MySQL, and taking backup of databases.
2. Install MYSQL as service.
 `C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install`

I had done clean installation of MYSQL 5.6 few days ago.
On first day everythng was fine. I could access city and world tables.

On next day I started getting below errors. Some were I read to run mysqld at admin level.
And it solved problem, but I couldn't access city and world table anymore.

On third day. I am getting only this errors.

Note: MYSQL service running previously fine, when firewall, antivirus (avast) and apache was running.

When run on admin mode :

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p localhost
Enter password: ***********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p localhost
Enter password: *
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p localhost
Enter password:
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'localhost'
```

When run on user mode (who is admin also) :

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p localhost
Enter password: ***********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p localhost
Enter password: *
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p localhost
Enter password:
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'localhost'
```

Not able to start MYSQL Service from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Service
Error Message ; WIndows could not start the MYSQL56 service on Local Computer
Error 1067 THe process terminated unexpectedly

Regards : Msinfo

Comment: How comes you get those error messages if you (supposedly) don't have a MySQL instance running?

Comment: So how I do that? I tried from Administrative Tools > Service > but it gives above error.

Comment: Is `localhost` your password? Maybe you meant `mysql -u root -h localhost`?

Comment: Thanks! I missed -h. But now problem is 1. root has password, but if i keep it null, it works, if i type password it fails. 2. when it works (without pw) it doesn't show default tables like city and world in default database. (which i previously accessed and practiced upon). Could you guess what has happened in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "-h" before "localhost" if you want to specify a host, otherwise just remove "localhost" and it should work fine, considering a running server on your system.

Also, MySQL server is "mysqld.exe" not "mysql.exe". mysqld (d stands for daemon) is the server which should run in background and does the actual stuff like creating tables,DBs etc. But mysql.exe just connects to the server and helps you to execute SQL queries. mysql.exe is just an interface to connect to server. If you want to know why your server (windows service in your case) is not starting, you should see the XXX.log in your MySQL server installation folder under Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

try by creating the database in MySql by the respective name "localhost"
eg: create database localhost;
by doing this you can clear the below error
**ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'localhost'**

hope i am correct

Thanks,
Daya